# Populating table with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getjson

I am trying to populate an HTML table using the JSON string retrieved from a $.getJSON() call. The $.getJSON() call is working fine. But I am not able to populate an html table with the retrieved json data. Please help me with my code..I'm new to this..

```
function loadTable(result){
    if(result.groups="no"){
        var num_rows = result.noofteams;
        var rows = "";

        for(var i=0;i<num_rows;i++){
        rows +='<tr>'+result.noofteams+'</tr>';         

        }
        $("#container").append(rows);
```

Here *result* is the json object that i am receiving. *result.noofteams* is giving proper value (i have checked it). But the problem is, i am unable to populate *#container* with *result.noofteams* Please help..

Comment: Can you post your html table structure?

Comment: Can you output the JSON string and post it here?

Comment: <table id="container">
<tr>

</tr> 
 
</table>

Comment: use == instae3d of = in if condition

Comment: @ Ian its a simple json string: {"noofteams":"20"}

Comment: So you want 20 rows containing the string '20'? Huh?

Comment: where is `groups` with value `no` in JSON???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

u used `=` while u need `==` or `===` for conditions

```
    function loadTable(result){
        if(result.groups==="no"){
            var num_rows = result.noofteams;
            var rows = "";

            for(var i=0;i<num_rows;i++){
            rows +='<tr><td>'+result.noofteams+'</td></tr>';         

            }
            $("#container").append(rows);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Add `<td>` they are important as well

Comment: {"noofteams":"20","groups":"no"}

Comment: well it sounds freaky..but i am getting the output now, after including <td></td> in the rows variable string..

Comment: oops..just now i added answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's much cleaner to work with JSON like so...

```
for (i in result) {
    rows += '<tr>' + result[i]['noofteams'] + '</tr>';
}
```